# Google Sheets: copying a formula to all cells in a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

When I add formulas to a google sheet they work fine, but when I add a new row the formulas are not copied.
to overcome this I found the formula arrayformula.
This is good for simple applications such as in cell D4 the following formula is added

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(B4:B), ,B4:B*C4:C))
```

[image: Short array]

However, when the formula is made a little more complicated it breaks down.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(and(isblank(B4:B),isblank(C4:C)), ,B4:B*C4:C))
```

[image: Broken formula]

This is still a very simple formula that seems to break, whereas the formulas in my sheet are often much more tricky such as

```
=if(Y5="","",filter('World Clock'!B:B,'World Clock'!A:A=Y5))
```

Which reads the data of the cell Y5 (which is the name of a timezone which i enter manually) and looks up another sheet named "World clock" which has a list of timezones and formulas for the current time in those timezones and copies that formula to this sheet.

[image: copied time]

[image: World Clock]

Does anyone know any formula to get this working? I know there is a way to do it via scripts and I'm sure I can figure that out myself, but if I can get the array formula or something similar working that would be much better as I already have a lot of scripts running in this file, it's starting to become slow.

Comment: Mehdi, welcome!  Certain functions don't work with ARRAYFORMULA, or only work in a limited way.  Typically functions that return arrays themselves, such as FILTER.  If you share a sample copy of your sheet, following this guide: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en, it may be easier to help you.  Please show clearly the result you would like to see, perhaps by entering the results by hand (not by formula).

Answer (score 2):

`AND()` and `OR()` doesn't work with `ARRAYFORMULA()` since it performs `AND()/OR()` method in the whole array.

If you want to do AND/OR per array. Use `* = AND()` or `+ = OR()` instead.

**Example:**

**AND:** `=ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(B4:B)*isblank(C4:C),,B4:B*C4:C))`

**OR:** `=ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(B4:B)+isblank(C4:C),,B4:B*C4:C))`

---

**Output:**

[image]

---

### (Update)

If you want to apply `ARRAYFORMULA()` in your `FILTER()` formula, you can use this formula in Trial Sheet `A2`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(B2:B="","",Vlookup(B2:B,'World Clock'!A:B,2,false)))
```

> NOTE: You need to remove other formula added from `A3` onward since it will block arrayformula() cell writing.

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work in many cells of the spreadsheet where i have used "and" or "or" but what do i do for filter?

Comment: Example sheet is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QGFcknvIy0wGJHa3gPmFkGzuOLM41W5QXi6aAqIBTOw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I thought you just sight the filter() as an example of your working function. If you want to use arrayformula() in your filter() function you can refer to the updated answer

Comment: If you feel like this answer is helpful, feel free to accept or upvote the answer as reference to others. Thanks